# How to add all remaining model fields to a django crispy form layout?

Tags: django-crispy-forms

I'm using [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/d-0/layouts.html), and I have a form with many fields.  I only want to customize a few of those fields, for example:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = ExampleModel
    fields = "__all__" # tons of fields

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('readonlyfield', readonly=True),
            # Add rest of fields here without explicitly typing them all out
        )
```

If I render this form, it will only have the one field.  How do I add the rest of them with their default layout values/settings?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this would be to use the [`get_fields` method of Django's Option class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_fields), which is available on your model's `._meta` property, combined with [star-unpacking](https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558). Like so:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = ExampleModel
    fields = "__all__" # tons of fields

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()

        # This list contains any fields that you are explicitly typing out / adding to the Layout
        manually_rendered_fields = ['readonlyfield',]

        # Next, create an array of all of the field name BESIDES the manually_rendered_fields
        all_other_fields = [f.name for f in self.model._meta.get_fields() if f not in manually_rendered_fields]

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('readonlyfield', readonly=True),
            # Add rest of fields here without explicitly typing them all out
            *all_other_fields,
            # if you needed to provide custom kwargs for the other fields, you could do something like this instead:
            *[Field(f, kwarg1=True, kwarg2=False) for f in all_other_fields],
        )
```